# Redirects in .htaccess - syntax - no effect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Situation: after a bunch of products on an online store were renamed, the URLs needed to be changed to match the new names. Redirects were set up to handle the old vs new URL conversion.

Since the old URL's could include these model names in several various places, a "keyword" approach was taken. In other words, "if *THIS_STRING* occurs somewhere in the requested URL, regardless of path, redirect to this new URL".

Some redirects work, since the old model name and the new model name is different:

```
RewriteRule ^.*(CC88SPECIAL).*$ http://www.example.com/widgets-DD99EXTREME [L,NC,R=301]
```

This would properly redirect any request containing "CC88SPECIAL" to the new URL.

Problem is, the same syntax could not be applied to models where the new name **included** the old name, i.e. AA55COMPLETE became AA55COMPLETE100:

```
RewriteRule ^.*(AA55COMPLETE).*$ http://www.example.com/widgets-AA55COMPLETE100 [L,NC,R=301]
```

The asterisk after the "keyword" would produce a loop.

So the format was changed to:

```
RewriteRule ^.*(AA55COMPLETE).$ http://www.example.com/widgets-AA55COMPLETE100 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Problem is, this has no effect. No loop, no error, no 503, just doesn't change the URL at all.

What am I doing wrong, and what's the correct syntax to make it right? I.e. match a specific string inside the requested URL, in **any** position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last rule failed because it does not match the requested uri /AA55COMPLETE because of the trailing **.** in your regex pattern. Dot in regex means to match one more character so its trying to match **/AA55COMPLETEA** instead . To redirect **/AA55COMPLETE** to **/AA55COMPLETE100** you can use

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^AA55COMPLETE/?$ /AA55COMPLETE100 [NC,L,R]
```